# gdb remote debugging of c++ process started via ssh: how to redirect stdin

Tags: linux, ssh, gdbserver

First, some background. I run a program by starting a process on a `remote_host` using `ssh`:

```
ssh -T remote_host "cd ~/mydir && ~/myprogram" < input.txt
```

The program, `myprogram`, reads stdin, which is attached to a local file `input.txt`.

Now, I need to remotely debug this program under gdb. If there was no stdin redirection, i.e. `< input.txt`, I would be able to do this using gdb's `target remote`, something like this (at gdb prompt):

```
(gdb) target remote | ssh -T remote_host gdbserver - myprogram
```

However, in the above example, I don't know how to attach `myprogram`'s stdin to `input.txt`.

Is there something that would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdbserver` doesn't read from stdin, so the program it invokes will have unfettered access to stdin. You should be able to do this:

```
ssh -T remote_host "cd ~/mydir && gdbserver :1234 ~/myprogram" < input.txt
```

where `1234` is an unused port. Then,

```
(gdb) target remote remote_host:1234
```

A drawback with this is that the `gdb-gdbserver` TCP connection won't be encrypted.